# Google Tasks API not using its increased quota

Tags: google-api, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I have a Windows Phone Google Tasks app that has been growing in popularity and a couple months ago I realized I was hitting the Google Tasks API courtesy quota of 5,000 daily requests.

I was getting 403 "DailyLimitExceeded". Following the advice of multiple forums, I requested an increase and was eventually granted 20,000 daily requests.. However, it still seems that the 5,000 limit is blocking me. To get around this I have created two more projects and have my app round robin users between them to help balance load.

I am using OAuth so I don't think I'm hitting the anonymous have limits. The projects all list the quota as 20,000 and track towards that but my original project starts erroring right around 5,000.. I have not hit that high of usage on the new projects yet. I have also tried turning off the API and back on, but that didn't help.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your project IDs with me? Private message me the details on G+: google.com/+EricKoleda

Comment: Just sent you a message.

Comment: I'm not seeing any notifications in G+.

Comment: I think I did it through the hangout first.. I just sent you a message, the right way - i think.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I've raised this issue with the team.

Comment: Your projects should have higher quota now, with the general problem being fixed early next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the quota increase process that prevented changes from going into effect. The bug has been fixed in code and should be released early next week.